# user defined data types in Cassandra

Tags: cassandra

I’ve a query regarding data modelling in Cassandra, would appreciate some suggestions here.

We’re trying to build a multi-tenant application where we expect data structure to be defined by the users. A user may define a data source, number of fields, their data types, ordering etc. and then upload data based on this structure. How can we design such an application on top of Cassandra since it doesn’t support a list of mixed data types. The current collection types are Map (same types)/Set/List (same type). Moreover, is it possible to query data based on the user defined entities?

Presently, we're thinking of maintaining a single Map  and convert all the values into blob before storing. It doesn't definitely allow to query (only with CONTAINS clause), but helps to structure the problem. Any other potential methods?

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to grasp exactly what you're trying to achieve but for what I can understand I think the map/set/list approach will not suffice you and you might hit performance problems. UDTs are similar in that regard. These are always loaded/read as a whole, like they were a blob.

Read [Collections](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.0/cql/cql_using/use_collections_c.html) for details.